# Creating an array of structs by adding dynamically some struct-elements

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, dynamic, struct

I've been struggling with C pointers for hours now. I'm trying to create a C program which manages flights. A flight contains the following:

```
flight-number, from, to, date, price

OS772,Vienna,New York,15.12.2018,638.00
```

Therefore, I'm reading a textfile of this given structure. On every line read, I need to create another struct and add it to my array or "list" of structs.

The struct looks like:

```
typedef struct flights {
    char *flnum;
    char *from;
    char *to;
    char *date;
    float price;
    struct person *fPerson;
}flights;
```

**My problem: Inside the function, the array of structs is created properly. But back in the main-function, the pointer to the array called 'flights **flight_list' is still NULL.**

Here is the code (only the necessary parts):

```
int main(void) {

    flights **flight_list = NULL;
    int numFlights = 0;

    if (!(numFlights = load_flights(flight_list)))      
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    /* value of flight_list = 0x0000 -> unchanged! */
    /* ... */
```

Function `short load_flights(flights **flight_list)`:

```
short load_flights(flights **flight_list) {

    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char file_buffer[256] = {};
    int i = 0;

    if (fp = fopen("flights.txt", "r")) {

        /* create array of structs */
        flight_list = (flights **)calloc(1, sizeof(int));

        while (!feof(fp)) {

            /* read current line of flight from textfile */
            fgets(file_buffer, sizeof(file_buffer), fp);

            /* create a new struct and add it to the array */
            if ((flight_list[i] = (flights *)calloc(1, sizeof(flights))) != NULL) {

                /* create every variable of the struct */
                flight_list[i]->flnum = (char *)calloc(1, strlen(ptr)+1);

                /* ... */

            }

            i++;
        }
    }
    else return 0;

    /* values of the struct-array are properly set; look in attached picture */

    return i;
}
```

This image was taken while debugging the array-creation process before `return i;`:

[image: viewing array of struct]

And here outside the function; inside main:

[image: viewing array of structs in main]

**So, why is my array of structs gone in the main-function?**

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *4 An argument may be an expression of any complete object type. In preparing for the call
to a function, the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the
corresponding argument. 93) A function may change the values of its parameters, but these changes cannot affect the values of the
arguments.*

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the address of a pointer variable to `load_flights`. Then `load_flights` needs to indirect through the variable to modify the caller's variable.

To handle the dynamic size of the input, you need to use `realloc()` each time through the loop to grow the array.

```
int main(void) {

    flights **flight_list = NULL;
    int numFlights = 0;

    if (!(numFlights = load_flights(&flight_list)))      
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    /* ... */
}

short load_flights(flights ***flight_list) {

    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char file_buffer[256] = {};
    int i = 0;

    if (fp = fopen("flights.txt", "r")) {

        /* create array of structs */
        flight_list **temp_flight_list = NULL;

        /* read current line of flight from textfile */
        while (fgets(file_buffer, sizeof(file_buffer), fp)) {
            // Grow the flight list array
            flights **new_flight_list = realloc(*flight_list, (i+1) * sizeof(flight_list *));
            if (new_flight_list == NULL) { // allocation failed, throw everything away
                for (int j = 0; j < i-1; j++) {
                    free(temp_flight_list[i]->flnum);
                    free(temp_flight_list[i]->from);
                    /* ... */
                    free(temp_flight_list[i]);
                }
                free(temp_flight_list);
                return 0;
            }
            temp_flight_list = new_flight_list;
            /* create a new struct and add it to the array */
            if ((temp_flight_list[i] = calloc(1, sizeof(flights))) != NULL) {
                // Parse the buffer ...
                /* create every variable of the struct */
                temp_flight_list[i]->flnum = calloc(1, strlen(ptr)+1);

                /* ... */

            } else { // allocation failed, throw everything away
                for (int j = 0; j < i-1; j++) {
                    free(temp_flight_list[i]->flnum);
                    free(temp_flight_list[i]->from);
                    /* ... */
                    free(temp_flight_list[i]);
                }
                free(temp_flight_list);
                return 0;
            }
            i++;
        }
        // Store new flight list in caller's variable
        *flight_list = temp_flight_list;
        return i;
    }
    else return 0;

}
```

See also

[Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

and

[Why is “while (!feof(file))” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)